# Configure SSRS for SharePoint 2013 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

So I have to configure SSRS on my box and i tried to search feature name "**Report Server Integration Feature**" and could not found and my search lead to below two post.

[Installing Reporting Services In SharePoint Mode](http://rajeshagadi.blogspot.com/2013/07/installing-reporting-services-in.html)

This blog details every details but for the first step it mentions of installing "**Reporting Services In SharePoint Mode**"

What I am looking is "**How can I convert this step in to PowerShell?**"

Is there a way to automate this in powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that there is a way to install SSRS in SharePoint (or native) mode.  The bad news is that it's a little complicated.

The trick is that it's done through the command line, not natively PowerShell.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492275(v=sql.110).aspx) is a link regarding command line installation of SSRS 2012 in SharePoint mode.  I also gather that you want to set it up in PowerShell so that you can run it unattended, so [here](http://www.ludovicocaldara.net/dba/sqlserver-2008r2-unattended-installation-and-configuration-via-powershell/) is an example of an installation script (for SQL Server 2008r2, not SSRS) that uses PowerShell.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I posted my answer but your help was g8. When I ran my command windows popup comes with the progress. is there a way where I can suppress that and show the progress in the console?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can suppress the progress window.  If you find a solution, please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did

So here is what I did

1. Created ini file by following steps mentioned [here](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/install-and-configure-sql-server-using-powershell-dsc)
2. Run below command

   $configFile = "c:\Ravi\SSRS.ini"

   $setupFile = "e:\setup.exe"
   $installCmd = "$setupFile /qs /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ConfigurationFile=""$configFile"" /ACTION=Install"

   Invoke-Expression $installCmd

**My ini file**

> [OPTIONS]
>
> ACTION="Install"
>
> ENU="True"
>
> QUIET="False"
>
> QUIETSIMPLE="False"
>
> UpdateEnabled="True"
>
> FEATURES=RS_SHP,RS_SHPWFE
>
> UpdateSource="MU"
>
> HELP="False"
>
> INDICATEPROGRESS="False"
>
> X86="False"
>
> INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files `(x86`)\Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> SQMREPORTING="False"
>
> RSSHPINSTALLMODE="SharePointFilesOnlyMode"
>
> ERRORREPORTING="True"
>
> INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
>
> IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"